# MATLAB - read comma separated text file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a file that is created from a software(HyperView).
The file doesn't have a file extension.
When I open it with WordPad, the following appears:

```
 Node ID,

19,
18,
17,
16,
15,
14,
```

I want to to add the numbers to a vector.

I tried load, csvread, textread, textscan and etc. Any ideas what (and how) to use or give me an idea how to determine the file type, so I can share it with you?

Windows XP, MATLAB R2012a

Comment: Are there many files that you can't copy them in `text`?

Comment: Go to `folder options > view > Hide file extensions` It's for `7` but I think it's the same for `xp`

Comment: Yes, I loop through several files.

@Kamtal: I have the files extensions shown for the other files, so I guess it's just created without a file extension

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are in a `text` file, you can use

```
fid = fopen('1.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %*s', ...
    'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);

C{1}

19
18
17
16
15
14
```

Comment: with this code fid is created as a class "double" variable with value "=3" wich results in C = []

Comment: @ViharChervenkov, but I tested it for text file and it works fine.